# EXCEL vba - extract numbers from cell and paste into two different columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a load of random text and numbers in column A like so:

```
Column A

    Row 1 = 471806121601 5205569 - 0007 Standard White Toilet Tissue 27 
    Row 2 = 471814121601 5206177 - 0014 Premium White Toilet Tissue 6 
    Row 3 = 471814121601 5206178 - 0007 Premium White Toilet Tissue 27
    Row 4 = 471806121601 5206180 - 0014 Premium Kitchen Towel 2x75l 6
```

I have about 2000 lines in total. In each cell, is a Purchase order number (12 digits) and an item number next to it (7 digits).

I am trying to extract the po number and put it into column B and extract the item number and put it into column C

```
Column B        Column C
471806121601    5205569 
471814121601    5206177 
471814121601    5206178 
471806121601    5206180
```

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim cell As Range
Dim arr As Variant, arrElem As Variant

With Worksheets("Orders") '<--| change "Strings" to your actual worksheet name
    For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        arr = Split(Replace(cell.Value, "  ", " "), " ") '<--| change "A"'s to your actual relevant column index
        For Each arrElem In arr
          If IsNumeric(arrElem) Then
            If Len(arrElem) = 12 Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = arrElem
          End If
        Next arrElem
    Next cell
End With

Dim cell2 As Range
Dim arr2 As Variant, arrElem2 As Variant

With Worksheets("Orders") '<--| change "Strings" to your actual worksheet name
    For Each cell2 In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        arr2 = Split(Replace(cell2.Value, "  ", " "), " ") '<--| change "A"'s to your actual relevant column index
        For Each arrElem2 In arr2
          If IsNumeric(arrElem2) Then
            If Len(arrElem2) = 7 Then cell2.Offset(0, 3).Value = arrElem2
          End If
        Next arrElem2
    Next cell2
End With

End Sub
```

This code does work. However it takes absolutely ages and only does one line at a time...Slowly.

Is there a quicker way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: just use `split(string,delimiter)(0)` and `(1)` why replace the space, just use that as the delim.  If Row # is in, then use (1) and (2), or you could consider `split(split(input,"-")," ")` maybe a little faster, not sure though.  Also, once you're done no need to complete the loop, so consider, do until with flags rather than for next, although `exit for` is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PO and IN are always the same length in col B put

```
=MID(A2, 1, 12)
```

And in col C

```
=MID(A2, 14, 7)
```

However if your number change but are always the first two swap the above for,

```
=MID(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)
```

And

```
=MID(A2, FIND(" ", A2, 1)+1, 7)
```

Respectively.

Answer (score 0):

just use `split(string,delimiter)(0)` and `(1)` why replace the space, just use that as the delim. If Row # is in, then use (1) and (2), or you could consider `split(split(input,"-")," ")` maybe a little faster, not sure though. Also, once you're done no need to complete the loop, so consider, do until with flags rather than for next, although `exit for` is available

Formula wise, it could be done using something like this

```
=MID(D1,FIND("é",SUBSTITUTE(D1," ","é",3)),FIND("é",SUBSTITUTE(D1," ","é",4))-FIND("é",SUBSTITUTE(D1," ","é",3)))
```

and

```
=MID(D1,FIND("é",SUBSTITUTE(D1," ","é",4)),FIND("é",SUBSTITUTE(D1," ","é",5))-FIND("é",SUBSTITUTE(D1," ","é",4)))
```